# how can i parameterize datasource properties on Spring 4?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

I am using Spring 4.16. I want to parameterize my persistence data. This is my config right now:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PersistenceConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManager = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManager.setDataSource(this.dataSource());
        entityManager.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {"com.example.movies.domain"});
        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        entityManager.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        entityManager.setJpaProperties(this.properties());
        return entityManager;
    }

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sarasa_db");
    dataSource.setUsername("root");
    dataSource.setPassword("mypassword");
    return dataSource;
}

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    private Properties properties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "false");
        return properties;
    }

}
```

And i want to parameterize on my application.properties all things i can. First of all, i want to put in datasource properties (so as i was reading, is possible that spring builds my datasource automatically, but apparently that is only using JdbcTemplate...):

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sarasa_db
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=mypassword
```

And, if it's possible, all the Properties's properties, which i couldn't find nothing in doc

Do you know how could i do it ?

---

### EDIT

This is my DAO implementation

```
@Configuration
@Import(PersistenceConfiguration.class)
public class DAOConfiguration {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Bean
    public ClientDAO clientDAO() {
        SimpleJpaRepository<Client, String> support = this.getSimpleJpaRepository(Client.class);
        return new MySQLClientDAO(support);
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    @Description("Hibernate repository helper")
    protected <T> SimpleJpaRepository<T, String> getSimpleJpaRepository(Class<T> domainClass) {
        return new SimpleJpaRepository<T, String>(domainClass, this.entityManager);
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot by any chance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

First define `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` bean somewhere in your Spring configuration:

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    ppc.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("application.properties"));
    return ppc;
}
```

This configuration assumes that `application.properties` file is placed at the root of your classpath.

After setting up the property placeholder configurer you can access the properties in your database configuration class like so:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PersistenceConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String jdbcUrl;
    // ...

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
       DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
       dataSource.setUrl(jdbcUrl);
       // ...
    }
}
```

If you want an easy way to parametrize all properties, you should take a look at [Spring Boot](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html). It uses the `application.properties` file to automatically create data source with those properties, and many other things. This is probably the automatic datasource creation you mentioned in your question.

Comment: thanks for your answer. But by your way, if i want to add a property, for example, i have to touch the configurations. That is why i want to do it automatically with application.context, so Spring read properties and creates my dataSource witih all aditional propoerties...

Comment: @user2601512 If you want Spring to create data source and other beans for you based on application.properties you probably want to be using Spring Boot as I mentioned at the end of my answer :)

Comment: Ohhh that is exactly what i wanted. I mean i saw it before but i thought that it was just for Spring jbdc. Thanks!!!